# lsusb listing the device but not accessible on serial port

Tags: centos, java, devices, lsusb

I connected a device using USB port. The device drivers are installed. I would like to access it from serial port.

Using `lsusb` it lists the device as:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 106f:0003 MyUSBDeviceManufacturerName
```

I want help on how to figure out why it is not listing / mounting as usb serial port.
I want to be able to send or receive bytes to it from my application.

Comment: Worth adding details of what your device is ?  Manufacturer, model etc ?

Comment: Most USB devices **don't** present a serial-port-like interface. The [USB ID Repository](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/) indicates the vendor ID 106f belongs/belonged to "Money Controls Holdings Ltd", which in 2010 became part of what is now known as "Crane Payment Innovations". It manufactures various kinds of money handling and validation devices. The product ID 0003 is unknown. The output of `lsusb -d 106f:0003 -v` would be helpful in identifying what kind of USB interface is currently presented by the device.